# change the font size to footnote size in the entire forest environment

Tags: fontsize, tikz-trees

[image][image]I have been trying to change the font size in the entire forest environment to footnote size but it doesn't seem to work. I have read the previous, related posts but the answers offered there did not work either, like encapsulating the entire tree with \fontsize, declaring a new font size+family, or changing it for each node separately. Here is my code >>>

```
\begin{figure}[H] % Set the entire figure in footnote size
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        align=left, % Aligns all nodes to the left
        edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
        l sep'+=10pt,
        fork sep'=10pt, 
        % Set the font size of the nodes to footnote size
    },
    forked edges,
    if level=0{
        inner xsep=0pt,
        tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
    }{},
    before typesetting nodes={
        if level=3{
            content={
                \begin{description}[labelindent=1em, labelwidth=0pt, leftmargin=1em, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, font=\footnotesize] % Set the level 3 nodes' content in footnote size
                    \item[\textbullet] #1
                \end{description}
            }
        }{}
    }
    [Types of relations
        [Expansion
            [Elaboration
                [- Explanation\\- Exemplification\\- Specification\\- Identification]
            ]
            [Extension
                [- Collection\\- Variation\\- Sequence\\- Response\\- Alternation]
            ]
            [Enhancement
                [- Spatio-temporal\\- Manner\\- Cause\\- Effect\\- Condition\\- Means\\- Purpose\\- Justification\\- Concession\\- Motivation\\- Enablement\\- Restatements\\- Summary]
            ]
        ]
        [Projection
            [Speech]
            [Thought]
        ]
        [Decoration
            [Various forms\\and types]
        ]
    ]
    \end{forest}
    \caption{Logico-semantic relations between words and images according to \textcite{kong2006taxonomy}}
    \label{fig:Figures}
\end{figure}
```

Loaded packages>

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}



%------LAYOUT--------------------------------------------------------------------
\geometry{
 left=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=35mm,
 bottom=35mm
}
\usepackage{float}

%------PARAGRAPHS---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%------GRAPHICS-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

%------ENUMERATION--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{researchquestions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[researchquestions]{label*={RQ\arabic*}}
\setlist{nosep}

%------SPACING-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

%------FOOT_HEAD---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE]{\small\upshape\color{gray!70}\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\upshape\color{gray!70}\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ / #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}

%------TABLES_FIGURES-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

%------COLOR-------------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{100, 220, 220}
\definecolor{kuleuven}{RGB}{29,141,176}
\definecolor{kuleuven1}{RGB}{82,189,236}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}


%------REFERENCES---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={black}
}
```

Comment: If I load `\usepackage[edges]{forest}\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` and `biblatex`, the tree is typeset in footnote size.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your suggestion. I had the same packages, and the issue persists. I should maybe add that I use overleaf. It is possible that there is some conflict of packages? 

%------TABLES_FIGURES-------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%--------------------------

Comment: Please, add to the question, not in comments

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Comment: You do get `\footnotesize`: indeed the font in the tree is the same as in the caption, namely 10 point size. If you want a smaller font in the tree, declare `\scriptsize` instead of `\footnotesize`.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the output. Am I just imagining things, or is the text in the tree still bigger :P? The caption is indeed footnotesize

Comment: No, the text in the tree is exactly the same size as in the caption. Add `\fontname\font` to one of the tree labels and at the end of the caption. In either case you will see “ec-lmr10” appearing.

Comment: This is accurate. Thanks for your help. I made a minimal working example and the code works indeed. Maybe it just looks weird in this particular doc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this answer but please try it. I have a feeling that this might have been asked before. The normal answer is to run LaTeX a second time. Please let me know if that works and if you are able to remind me why that is supposed to work. Thank you, GOM

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a victim of an optical illusion. The text in the tree labels may *appear* to be slightly bigger than the text in the caption, but this is due to the missing context.

Visual experiment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

{\centering\footnotesize Expansion\par}

\bigskip

\footnotesize\noindent
Logico-semantic relations between words and images according to
some article that I don't know about.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you fix your eye to “Expansion” it will appear larger than the text in the caption. But they're exactly the same. Further example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

{\centering\footnotesize \fontname\font\par}

\bigskip

\footnotesize\noindent
Logico-semantic relations between words and images according to
some article that I don't know about. \fontname\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that `\fontname\font` prints exactly the same. Try with your code by adding `\fontname\font` in one of the labels and at the end of the caption. You will see “ec-lmr10” in both instances.

If you want a distinctly smaller font for the tree, you can declare `\scriptsize`.

I take the opportunity to suggest some changes in your preamble, separating package loading from setup.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % <--- no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage{float} % don't

%------PARAGRAPHS---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%------GRAPHICS-----------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

%------ENUMERATION--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}

% spacing
\usepackage{setspace}

%------FOOT_HEAD---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%------TABLES_FIGURES-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


% references
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% settings

% layout
\geometry{
 left=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=35mm,
 bottom=35mm,
 headheight=13.6pt, % <--- as suggested by fancyhdr
}

% lists
\newlist{researchquestions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[researchquestions]{label*={RQ\arabic*}}
\setlist{nosep}

% spacing
\singlespacing

% header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE]{\small\upshape\color{gray!70}\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\upshape\color{gray!70}\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter\ / #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}

% captions
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

% hyperref

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={black}
}

% colors
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{100, 220, 220}
\definecolor{kuleuven}{RGB}{29,141,176}
\definecolor{kuleuven1}{RGB}{82,189,236}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.6}

% resources
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\scriptsize

    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        align=left, % Aligns all nodes to the left
        edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
        l sep'+=10pt,
        fork sep'=10pt, 
        % Set the font size of the nodes to footnote size
    },
    forked edges,
    if level=0{
        inner xsep=0pt,
        tikz={\draw [thick] (.children first) -- (.children last);}
    }{},
    before typesetting nodes={
        if level=3{
            content={
                \begin{description}[labelindent=1em, labelwidth=0pt, leftmargin=1em, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, font=\footnotesize] % Set the level 3 nodes' content in footnote size
                    \item[\textbullet] #1
                \end{description}
            }
        }{}
    }
    [Types of relations
        [Expansion
            [Elaboration
                [- Explanation\\- Exemplification\\- Specification\\- Identification]
            ]
            [Extension
                [- Collection\\- Variation\\- Sequence\\- Response\\- Alternation]
            ]
            [Enhancement
                [- Spatio-temporal\\- Manner\\- Cause\\- Effect\\- Condition\\- Means\\- Purpose\\- Justification\\- Concession\\- Motivation\\- Enablement\\- Restatements\\- Summary]
            ]
        ]
        [Projection
            [Speech]
            [Thought]
        ]
        [Decoration
            [Various forms\\and types]
        ]
    ]
    \end{forest}

\caption{Logico-semantic relations between words and images according 
  to \textcite{kong2006taxonomy}}
\label{fig:Figures}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for an extensive explanation. I followed the suggestions (\fontname\font). The font in caption is indeed 10pt, whereas at the 3rd level nodes it showed 10.95pt for whatever reason.